# Simple question: How to do variable concatenation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In php I can have something like this:

```
$animal = 'horse';

$animal += ', tigers';
```

then the value of animals would be "horse, tigers". How do I do this type of variable concatenation in JavaScript?

Comment: You could have tried it out yourself before asking it on SO.

Comment: That's actually not how you do it in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

```
var szTest = "";
szTest += "One";
szTest += ", Two";
```

Comment: I want to downvote your hungarian (but I won't this time). Not only is hungarian out-dated in the first place, but javascript doesn't use zero-terminated strings, and thus your sz prefix is wrong.

Comment: @Joel, Systems Hungarian is outdated.  Apps Hungarian can sometimes be useful.  Another problem with this answer (and the question) is that this *isn't* how you do it in PHP.

Comment: @Joel agree completely, the sz makes every variable name look like some Hungarian guy's name. Ugh.

Comment: And for the hungarian notation stuff Going thru this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198825/best-way-to-get-rid-of-hungarian-notation

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can use the `+` to concatenate strings like so,

```
'horse' + ', tigers';
```

---

In PHP the string concatenation operator is `.`. So, your example should be:

```
$animal = 'horse';

$animal .= ', tigers';
```

Comment: You can also use `+=` with roughly the expected effect (either way a new string is created).

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen Yes you can. The 'official' concatenation operator is the `.` as per the documentation. However, I will edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: I wasn't clear.  I meant you can use `+=` in **JavaScript**.  If you do so in PHP, it will fail the same way `+` does (PHP will coerce the string to 0).

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen Oops, misinterpreted that. I should have tested it out anyway. Thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Surprise:

```
'horse' + ', tigers'; // 'horse, tigers'
```

Now read a good tutorial before asking a thousand more questions:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Answer (score 0):

```
var $animal = 'horse';

$animal += ', tigers';
```